# Is there a preferred manner for sending data over a web socket connection?

Tags: c#, python, json, websocket, binary

Is there a 'correct' or preferred manner for sending data over a web socket connection?

In my case, I am sending the information from a C# application to a python (tornado) web server, and I am simply sending a string consisting of several elements separated by commas. In python, I use rudimentary techniques to split the string and then structure the elements into an object.
e.g:

```
'foo,0,bar,1'
```

becomes:

```
object = {
    'foo': 0,
    'bar': 1
}
```

In the other direction, I am sending the information as a JSON string which I then deserialise using Json.NET

I imagine there is no strictly right or wrong way of doing this, but are there significant advantages and disadvantages that I should be thinking of? And, somewhat related, is there a consensus for using string vs. binary formats?

Comment: JSON is often a preferred transfer format because pretty much every language now has functions for converting to/from the native language format and JSON.

Comment: Both answers are appreciated. I've more-or-less headed in the JSON serialiser direction though I remain curious (and probably will yet try) a binary serialiser as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a *custom* encoding (eg, as "k,v,..") is *different* than 'using binary'.

*It is still text*, just a rigid under-defined one-off hand-rolled format that must be manually replicated. (What happens if a key or value contains a comma? What happens if the data needs to contain nested objects? How can null be interpreted differently than '' or 'null'?)

While JSON is definitely the most *ubiquitous* format for WebSockets one shouldn't (for interchange purposes) write JSON by hand - *one uses an existing serialization library on both ends*. (There are many reasons why JSON is ubiquitous which are covered in other answers - this doesn't mean it is always the 'best' format, however.)

To this end a *binary* serializer can also be used (BSON being a trivial example as it is effectively JSON-like in structure and operation). Just replace `JSON.parse` with `FORMATX.parse` as appropriate.

The only requirements are then:

- There is a suitable serializer/deserializer for the *all* the clients and servers. JSON works well here because it is so popular and there is no shortage of implementations.

  There *are* various binary serialization libraries with *both* Python and C# libraries, but it will require finding a 'happy intersection'.
- The serialization format can represent the data. JSON usually works sufficiently and it has a *very nice 1-1 correspondence with basic object graphs* and simple values. It is also inherently schema-less.

  Some formats are better are certain tasks and have different characteristics, features, or tool-chains. However most concepts (and arguably most DTOs) can be mapped onto JSON easily which makes it a good 'default' choice.

The other differences between different *kinds* of binary and text serializations is most mostly dressing - but if you'd like to start talking about schema vs. schema-less, extensibility, external tooling, metadata, non-compressed encoded sizes (or size after transport compression), compliance with a specific existing protocol, etc..

.. but the point to take away is **don't create a 'new' one-off format**. Unless of course, you just like making wheels or there is a *very specific* use-case to fit.

Answer (score 0):

First advice would be to use the same format for both ways, not plain text in one direction and JSON in the other.

I personally think `{'foo':0,'bar':1}` is better than `foo,0,bar,1` because everybody understands JSON but for your custom format they might not without some explanations. The idea is you are inventing a data interchange format when JSON is already one and @jfriend00 is right, pretty much every language now understands JSON, [Python included](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Regarding text vs binary, there isn't any consensus. As @ user2864740 mentions in the comments to my answer as long as the two sides understand each other, it doesn't really matter. This only becomes relevant if one of the sides has a preference for a format (consider for example opening the connection from the browser, using JavaScript - for that people might prefer  JSON instead of binary).

My advice is to go with something simple as JSON and design your app so that you can change the wire format by swapping in another implementation without affecting the logic of your application.

Comment: One would use `FORMATX.parse(..)`. This has nothing to do with 'binary' vs 'text', only 'some hand created format' vs 'some format with a JavaScript (and C#) implementation'. Binary transfer specifications cover the encoding rules (including endianess), just as the JSON specification defines JSON.

Comment: While most of the answer has good advice that (3rd) paragraph is very misleading, as explained. As long as both sides understand the format (and there are several popular binary formats available with JavaScript support) then it doesn't really apply. Writing it *by hand* is different than 'using binary'. (And in the OPs case it was still 'text', just in a *by hand / custom* format.)

Comment: I was just stating that binary has some disadvantages over text given that we are taking about websockets connections here which most of the times have one end inside the browser. And the OP did ask... I'll rephrase, see if you like it better.

Comment: But it is *misleading* because unless one is incorrectly (as in, not using an appropriate serializer) generating the JSON by hand then it is as simple as replacing `JSON.parse` with `FORMATX.parse`. While there are some differences with formats used (eg. some require separate schemas, not all map 1-1 onto adhoc JavaScript graphs), consider [`BSON.parse`](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson) as example illustrating the previous point.